# How to build ffmpeg and run on android like vanevery's ffmpeg library

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I want to know how to build ffmpeg files like [this ffmpeg library](https://github.com/vanevery/Android-MJPEG-Video-Capture-FFMPEG)

I trying to learn how to use ffmpeg like that but I failed.

Although I can run it's sample well, but when I change package name, it would be never work.

It may cause of 'ffmpeg' file will not found original package, then process failed.

And according to this library's issue, the library author say 'You need to rebuild the libs with your own configuration', but I don't know how to build like this library.

I had try many method to build, like [this](http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-ffmpeg-for-android/), but the result files look different with the library, and especially it missing the most important file 'ffmepg' that I need.

Please help me figure out this problem.

Comment: Did you search before posting?  Here's a top result from my search [wiki-CompilationGuide/Android](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Android)

Comment: I had try this result, but like I had said, the result is different with vanevery's ffmpeg library. I do not really understand those build process principle, could you tell me more detail?

Comment: Sorry I was pointing out a quick web search result, I don't have much free time to setup Ubuntu and try to build ffmpeg for Android.  I'll try another search when I get some time.